# 3D grid with python

Tags: python, 3d, grid

I have a set of data, 5 columns: (x,y,z,Temperature, Pressure), is not a regular mesh, is data from well logging. I would like to make a 3d grid in order to make some vertical cut. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you provide some example data input/output? I'm unsure if I understand the question.

Answer (score -1):

Your question isn't very clear about what you want. If it is a graph packages like seaborn and matplotlib can make 3D graphs that can display heatmap information.